# Why is my list not being converted to an array in .zshrc startup script?

Tags: zsh

I have the following script that works fine when called from the command line, however when I call the script from within my `~/.zshrc` file the list of sessions is not converted to an array.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

# Get tmux sessions and add option for a new one
TMUX_SESSIONS="$(tmux list-sessions -F "#S") \
  new";
echo ${TMUX_SESSIONS}

echo "Which tmux session, or enter string for a new one";
select TMUX_SESSION in ${TMUX_SESSIONS}; do
  case $TMUX_SESSION in
    new )
      while [[ "${TMUX_SESSION}" == "new" || "${TMUX_SESSION}" == "" ]]; do
        read -p "Session name: " TMUX_SESSION
        echo "\"${TMUX_SESSION}\""
      done
      tmux new -s ${TMUX_SESSION}
      ;;
    * )
      tmux attach -t ${TMUX_SESSION}
  esac

  break
done
```

Output when I run manually (as expected)…

```
api base limtool new
Which tmux session, or enter string for a new one
1) api
2) base
3) limtool
4) new
```

Output when run from `~/.zshrc`

```
api
base
limtool   new
Which tmux session, or enter string for a new one
1) api
base
limtool   new
```

This is on a Mac, for reference.

Comment: when I call it from my zshrc with `bash ~/listsessions` your script works. If you add the code and not inside a script to your zshrc make sure you use zsh syntax, which does only differ slightly. But I've checked it by editing in `env zsh` it still works. Also your script needs a way to catch if you're already inside a tmux session if you call it like I did or you'll get prompted after opening session. if it works for you like that I'll add this as an answer and delete comment.

Comment: Is this a bash or a zsh question? It might be simpler to only use one or the other of the shells.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that when you call it from you command line, you're using `bash` as the interpreter. When you call it from `.zshrc` you're using `zsh` as the interpreter. I know you're using `zsh` as the interpreter when running from `~/.zshrc` because the behavior you describe is the behavior of that shell.

Unfortunately your question leaves out a rather critical bit of information about **how** you are calling the script. There are several ways you could be doing this, but none of them have difference in behavior when run from the CLI or from another script (unless you have some esoteric configuration such as a `bash` binary in `$PATH` that is actually a `zsh` or some other sillyness). Some common ways:

1. `/path/to/script` - will use `bash` interpreter. More specifically it'll use `/bin/sh`. Your shebang (the first line) is broken. It needs to be `#!/usr/bin/env`, not `#/usr/bin/env`.
2. `bash /path/to/script` - will use `bash` interpreter.
3. `zsh /path/to/script` - will use `zsh` interpreter.
4. `. /path/to/script` - will use `zsh` interpreter (assuming that's the active shell).

Now you can also just fix your script so it works properly in both shells. The fix is to use an array, and not a string, to store the values you get from `tmux list-sessions`.

```
TMUX_SESSIONS=( $(tmux list-sessions -F "#S") new )
echo "${TMUX_SESSIONS[@]}"

echo "Which tmux session, or enter string for a new one";
select TMUX_SESSION in "${TMUX_SESSIONS[@]}"; do
```

Comment: When you say I'm running is using bash from the command line... if that because of the (broken) shebang?  Does that not cause it to run under back on startup as well?  I'm a little confused, as I fixed this by using `sh -c "/paht/to/script"`in my .zshrc file, so I'm not sure it matters which shell I launch is using, does it?